# How can I restrict specific row of datagrid from being selected in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in which I am marking the duplicate record in red color using DataGrids LoadingRow event.

**Xaml:**

```xaml
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" 
                  EnableRowVirtualization="False" 
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                  CanUserAddRows="false" 
                  Width="Auto" 
                  MaxHeight="216" 
                  LoadingRow="dataGrid_LoadingRow">
      <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding FullName, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Name"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Address.Zip, Mode=OneWay}" Header="PLZ"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Address.City, Mode=OneWay}" Header="ORT"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Code Behind for Loading_Row:**

```
private void dataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        TempObject temp = e.Row.DataContext as TempObject;

        if (temp.IsDuplicate)
        {
            e.Row.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#0066ff"));
        }                     
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

**Solutions tried:**

```
e.Row.IsEnable = false; (dataGrid_LoadingRow)
```

Issue: It works when we try to click on row, row did not get selected.
But when I select other valid row and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then all rows got selected.

Is there any other way to do this? Please provide answers with sample code.

Comment: what you really want to do by making the particular row disable? Instead it is better not to add duplicate rows.

Comment: Hi @Gopi, actually the data displayed in the grid view is returned by another dll, so in our side we want to show the duplicate record to user. We have functionality that using records selected will be displayed on map.So we want to restrict those records to be added on map by restricting the selection.

Comment: You can clear the map every time and display only the selected record or else you just maintain the already plotted records on map into some list and before plotting check in the list if particular record is there or not. If not there then plot in the map

Comment: Thanks @gopi, We have requirement that duplicate records can not be selected and they will have red background color, is there any way to restrict the selection, because we can not change the requirement

Comment: There is no way to do what you want with the standard WPF `DataGrid`. You can only mimic the "disabled" selection possibility by changing the rows' styles, setting `IsHitTestVisible` to `False`, or any other way. However, you can create your own control that provides such functionality. Or maybe there are some WPF controls on the market that already can do that.

Comment: Try with WPFToolkit DataGrid. I think it is possible with that.